# Why can't type inference determine type from constraints

Tags: c#, generics

I have made an interface so that I can try and make some repeated code generic.

```
public interface IIdentifiable<T>
{
    T Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have a class that works with an entity, with the constraint of `IIdentifiable<T>`

```
public class MyClass<TEntity, TId>
    where TEntity : IIdentifiable<TId> {}
```

But now whenever I use `MyClass` I have to pass in `TId` even though there is only one valid type for `TId`.

```
public class MyEntity : IIdentifiable<Guid> {}

var foo = new MyClass<MyEntity>(); // Error
var bar = new MyClass<MyEntity, Guid>();
```

In C++ I can do this:

```
template<typename T>
struct IIdentifiable
{
    using id_type = T;

    T id;
};

template<typename TEntity, typename TId = typename TEntity::id_type>
struct MyClass {};

MyClass<MyEntity> foo;
```

Is there a C# equivalent?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `MyClass` - it doesn't use `TEntity` anywhere.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I simplified it for the sake of the question, but in my use case the constructor takes a `TEntity`.

Comment: @maddisoj In some cases you may get away with a factory method by leveraging type inference, but you could benefit from telling us how you would use these interfaces, so we could advise you of a proper solution, see [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271659).

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Problem is I can't really post more as it's part of a closed source product. What I have works I just didn't like having to repeat the entity's Id type everywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> there is only one valid type for `TId`

**Wrong!** :)

Counterexample:

```
public class MyEntity : IIdentifiable<Guid>
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class MyOtherEntity : MyEntity, IIdentifiable<int>
{
    int IIdentifiable<int>.Id { get; set; }
}

var foo = new MyClass<MyOtherEntity>(); // So, which IIdentifiable should be used?
```

Besides, C# generics don't work like C++ templates, they're reified at runtime and have different constraints.

Comment: Well, yes, if you add other valid types then there are other valid types. In the original case, there is only one valid type...

Comment: @Rawling except there would need to be only one valid type at runtime. That's not so easy to ensure with dynamically loadable classes. The `where` constraint means *is-a*, not *is-exactly-a*.

Comment: `MyClass` is known at compile time; if it only has one valid `IIdentifiable` implementation then, can it gain another one at runtime?

Comment: In this case I would accept that the type cannot be inferred and expect an ambiguity error message. (Edit) And by answering Rawling's question I realized why this isn't possible.

Comment: @Rawling I believe you can create types at runtime using reflection.

Comment: @maddisoj well, I'd certainly like to have some more features from C++ generics in C#, but unfortunately that's not the case :/

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski i would consider this to be a feature of c#, since it is more precise as your example indicates